# Kickstarting VMWare ESX 4.1 (Error: No NIC with name bootif)

Tags: networking, vmware-esx, nic, pxe-boot, kickstart

I'm having an issue kickstarting an installation of VMWaare ESX Classic 4.1.  I've stripped down my kickstart a bit to just:

```
accepteula

keyboard us

auth

clearpart --firstdisk --overwritevmfs

url --url=10.16.0.1/cblr/ks_mirror/esx-classic-4.1.0-260247

rootpw --iscrypted $1$zZJa3g7g$mD8d.6QgbPku1QovQTAps/

timezone 'US/Pacific'

network --addvmportgroup=true --device=vmnic0 --bootproto=dhcp

part '/boot'  --fstype=ext3 --size=1100  --onfirstdisk
part 'none'  --fstype=vmkcore --size=110  --onfirstdisk
part 'datastore1'  --fstype=vmfs3 --size=8920 --grow  --onfirstdisk

virtualdisk 'esxconsole' --size=7920 --onvmfs='datastore1'

part 'swap'  --fstype=swap --size=916 --onvirtualdisk='esxconsole'
part '/var/log'  --fstype=ext3 --size=2000 --onvirtualdisk='esxconsole'
part '/'  --fstype=ext3 --size=5000 --grow --onvirtualdisk='esxconsole'

%post --interpreter=bash
```

However, when I attempt to use this kickstart during a PXE install with no additional kernel options, I get the following error:

```
There was a problem with the Network Device specified on the command line.
Error: No NIC found with name bootif
```

If I comment out the network line in the kickstart, the error changes to:

```
There was a problem with the Network Device specified on the command line.
Error: No NIC found with name eth0
```

How can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Why are you bothering, do you really need the SC?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with that abbreviation SC

Comment: Service Console. It's the primary difference between ESX and ESXi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try adding "IPAPPEND 2" to your pxe stanza.

Also, are you sure that the drivers for your nic exist in the installer you are trying to boot?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try setting `--device=eth0` in the network line? I looked at this:

- http://www.vmprofessional.com/index.php?content=kickstart_1
- http://communities.vmware.com/thread/197163

and that's the only mention of and always eth0.

EDIT: Since OP uses Cobbler, this is the important link:

- https://fedorahosted.org/pipermail/cobbler/2008-September/000824.html

Comment: I'll give it a shot, thanks.  I recall trying this and having something go wrong.

Comment: Well I tried that but the first error persisted, No NIC found with name bootif.

Comment: Do you have `ksdevice` parameter to kernel defined in your PXE config? Look here: http://blog.scottlowe.org/2010/03/02/pxe-booting-vmware-esx-40/

Comment: I've tried with it both defined (as vmnic0 and eth0) and not defined.  Unfortunately the error is still there.

Comment: That's a bummer - do you have any mention of `bootif` anywhere in your config files or is this some VMWare default?

Comment: Nope bootif doesn't show up anywhere at all that's why I'm so confused.  One detail that I left out is that I am using Cobbler (a provisioning system) to start the pxe boots.  However, this shouldn't be doing anything other than a normal pxe install. I'm stumped.

Comment: That might be an important detail - look here: https://fedorahosted.org/pipermail/cobbler/2008-September/000824.html. Try using `ksdevice=link` as suggested or try doing a regular PXE. And also - I think what Chopper3 meant is - why bother with PXE? Why not a regular install?

Comment: I am not familiar with Cobbler - are there any config files for it that you need to search for bootif? I suppose `/etc/cobbler/settings` given in the above link - any `bootif` there?

Comment: I found a bootif in /etc/cobbler/settings! -->                      
kernel_options:
    ksdevice: bootif
 I'm not sure what I should change it to though, nothing?

Comment: Again, not familiar with Cobbler, but try either `ksdevice=link` as specified in the post I linked or `ksdevice=eth0` to be specific.

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from the installer trying to parse the kernel boot command line BOOTIF=XXX parameter.  Check the boot command line with cat /proc/cmdline to see what you booted with.  BOOTIF it typically added by a PXE bootloader, but can also be found in grub.conf

Edit:

This can also happen if 'ksdevice=' or 'netdevice=' are set on the kernel cmdline